# Why is image rotating after capturing it through camera intent?

Tags: android

I have been stuck in camera for 6 days but not getting any proper solution. When I am capturing image through camera intent, image is being rotated. I tried to fix the orientation but sometimes it's not giving bitmap value in onActivityResult(). It shows a black screen when I try to set image in ImageView. Here is my code Please help me -

```
//call intent to capture image
captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) 
            {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,AlletConstants.CAPTURE_RECEIPT_IMAGE);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
});


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case AlletConstants.CAPTURE_RECEIPT_IMAGE:
            if(data != null)
            {
                Uri qrcodeImageUri = data.getData();
                bitmapReceiptImage = handleQrBarCodeImage(qrcodeImageUri);
                mImageCaptureUri = AlletCommonUtility.bitmapToUri(getActivity(), bitmapReceiptImage);
                doCrop();
                AlletCommonUtility.showToast(getActivity(),"Uri = "+mImageCaptureUri);
            }

            break;

        case AlletConstants.CROP_RECEIPT_FROM_CAMERA:
            if(data != null)
            {
                Bundle qrcodeextras = data.getExtras();
                if (qrcodeextras != null) {
                    Bitmap cropBitmap = qrcodeextras.getParcelable("data");
                    receiptImageView.setImageBitmap(cropBitmap);
                    bitmapReceiptImage = cropBitmap;
                }

                File qrcodeFile = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                if (qrcodeFile.exists())
                    qrcodeFile.delete();
            }

            break;      

        default:
            break;
        }

    }




// use to get bitmap from uri 
    private Bitmap handleReceiptImage(Uri selectedImageUri)
    {       
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };  

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);  
        cursor.moveToFirst();  

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);  
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);  
        cursor.close(); 
        Bitmap bitmap = setCameraImageRotation(picturePath);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap setCameraImageRotation(String picturePath)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapQrBarImage = null;
         try {
                File f = new File(picturePath);
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
                int orientation =  exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);      
                AlletCommonUtility.showToast(getActivity(), "Orienattion = "+orientation);
                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                mat.postRotate(getImageOrientation(orientation));
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize= 4;
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
                bitmapQrBarImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);     

                if (bitmapQrBarImage != null) {
                     AlletCommonUtility.showToast(getActivity(), "CAMERA_PIC_SELECTION = "+bitmapQrBarImage);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
            }   
            catch(OutOfMemoryError oom) {
                Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
            }

         return bitmapQrBarImage;

    }



// Use to crop image
    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {       
            AlletCommonUtility.showToast(getActivity(), AlletMessage.NOT_CROP_IMAGE);           
            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                startActivityForResult(i, AlletConstants.CROP_RECEIPT_FROM_CAMERA);

            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title    = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon     = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getActivity(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, AlletConstants.CROP_RECEIPT_FROM_CAMERA); 
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }



// use to rotate captured image from device camera 
public static int getImageOrientation(int rotation)
    {
         int angle = 0;

            switch (rotation) {
            case 0:
                angle = 90;
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                angle = 90;
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                angle = 180;
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                angle = 270;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return angle;

    }
```

I am getting image in landscape mode but not in potrait mode. Camera preview automatically rotates by 90 degrees after capturing image.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the image's EXIF data. You need to use a rotation method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build-in Camera orientation and orientation of device the pictures will have different rotations. You check the rotation of your particular image through `ExifInterface`.

```
/**
 * @param filename      Path to image file
 * @param captureTime   Time when image file was created
 */
public static int extractExifOrientationTagFromImageFile(String filename, long creationTime) {
    /* The issue is on some devices, there's a bug that makes the picture taken saved in your app folder without proper 
       exif tags while a properly rotated image is saved in the android default folder (even though it shouldn't be).
       Now what we do is recording the time when we're starting the camera app. Then we query
       the Media Provider to see if any pictures were saved after this timestamp we've saved. That means most likely Android OS 
       saved the properly rotated picture in the default folder and of course put an entry in the media store and we can use the 
       rotation information from this row.  */
    int imageRotation = -1;
    long imageFileSize = new File(filename).length();

    Cursor mediaFileCursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE }, 
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " >= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(creationTime / 1000 - 1) }, 
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
    if((mediaFileCursor != null) && (mediaFileCursor.getCount() != 0)) {
        while(mediaFileCursor.moveToNext()) {
            long mediaFileSize = getLongFromCursor(mediaFileCursor, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE);
            // Extra check to make sure that we are getting the orientation from the proper file
            if(mediaFileSize == imageFileSize) {
                imageRotation = getIntFromCursor(mediaFileCursor, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Now if the rotation at this point is still -1, then that means this is one of the devices with proper rotation information. */
    if(imageRotation == -1) {
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageRotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
    }

    return imageRotation;
}

private static final int COLUMN_NOT_EXISTS = -1;

public static Long getLongFromCursor(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex;
    if((columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)) != COLUMN_NOT_EXISTS) {
        return cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Integer getIntFromCursor(Cursor cursor, String columnName) {
    int columnIndex;
    if((columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)) != COLUMN_NOT_EXISTS) {
        return cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when you have your image rotation you can rotate it's bitmap properly:

```
int imageRotation = extractExifOrientationTagFromImageFile(lastCapturedMediaUriPath, cameraAppInvokeTime);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
switch(imageRotation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
final Bitmap loadedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but can you please tell me how will I get CameraInvokeAppTime for extractOrientationTagFromImageFile().

Comment: Before invoking Camera app by intent simply call System.currentTimeMillis() method and pass the value it returns to extractOrientationTagFromImageFile().

Comment: Hi Michal, My rotation problem still not solved. I am using LG device. When I am capturing image and preview shown in Potrait mode, it does not set image in image view & when preview shown in landscape mode I am getting very small size bitmap like icon. Please help me.